# IllegalArgumentException: invalid sequence element when creating SpinnerListModel

Tags: java, swing, list, illegalargumentexception, jspinner

I am trying to make a JSpinner with a set of values which step less and less as they decrease, so I created a function to generate these values and I add 100 values to a list, then try to create a SpinnerListModel with the list as it's source. This gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid sequence element
    at javax.swing.SpinnerListModel.setValue(SpinnerListModel.java:185)
    at com.fractalexplorer.main.RangeSelector.setValue(RangeSelector.java:106)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
SpinnerListModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerListModel(constructSpinnerModelSource());

public List<Double> constructSpinnerModelSource()
{
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int steps = 100;

    for(int i = 0; i <= steps; i++)
        list.add(getStep(i));

    return list;
}

public Double getStep(double x)
{
    return 2.25 * Math.pow(0.95, x);
}
```

The values range from 2 to 0.013321190745751494 currently, here are the last 12 values:

```
0.02341981115445541, 0.022248820596732638, 0.021136379566896003, 
0.020079560588551204, 0.01907558255912364, 0.018121803431167458,    
0.017215713259609085, 0.01635492759662863, 0.015537181216797197, 
0.014760322155957337, 0.01402230604815947, 0.013321190745751494
```

Comment: read API for implemented arrays types (return list;) in SpinnerListModel, excelent hint in answer by brunobastosg

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE? short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown if you try to set a value that does not belong in the JSpinner's list of values.

Example:

```
String[] values = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerListModel(values);
model.setValue("TWO"); // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: That was it, the value I was trying to set wasn't in the list! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have list of `Double` items but try to set value to `RangeSelector` instance.

Either try to add `RangeSelector` instances to the model or cast the range to Double when calling `setValue()`. In fact you try to set value which is not in the list and model can't accept the value.